# Uint8Array to string conversion difference between Firefox and Chromium

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, uint8array

I'm trying to convert binary data to string like this:

`var string = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(Uint8Array.from([1, 2, 3]));`

When I look for what variable `string` returns in Firefox, it shows expected string `"\u0001\u0002\u0003"`

Although when I do the same in Chrome, `string` returns an empty string `""`

Can someone, please, explain, what's going on?

Comment: Chrome tries to "display" values from output string in console. Try `JSON.stringify(new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(Uint8Array.from([1, 2, 3])))` in chrome.

Comment: On Chrome 67 I get a string of 3 unprintable characters, rendered as the empty square. The string consists of the proper unocode code points, as seen by `Array.from({length: string.length}, (v, k) => k).map ( idx => string.codePointAt(idx) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome console renders unprintable characters differently than firefox. Specifically, unprintable characters are rendered as the empty square. Nonetheless the string consists of the proper unicode code points.

The following one-liner (well ...) creates the `\u...` rendering.

```
Array.from(
    {length: string.length}
  , (v, k) => k
)
   .map ( idx => `\\u${string.codePointAt(idx).toString(16).padStart(4, '0')}`)
   .join()
;
```

Test it:

```js
let string = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(Uint8Array.from([1, 2, 3]));

console.log(`raw rep: '${string}'.`);
console.log(`code point rep: '${Array.from(
    {length: string.length}
  , (v, k) => k).map ( idx => `\\u${string.codePointAt(idx).toString(16).padStart(4, '0')}` 
).join("")}'.`);
```